# What's the best type to store a tabular data structure?

Tags: c#, data-structures

I'm developing an integration service provides for some web applications some functionality and services.

One of these service is executing custom queries on a specific database.

There are these methods: (`ExecuteScaler`, `ExecuteNonQuery`, `ExecuteTable`).

I've already implement the first two. Now, what's your suggestion for the return type of `ExecuteTable` ?

I need a simple data structure demonstrate a table. I've thought of `DataTable`, Do you have any other suggestion ?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the tabular data is arbitrary, and needs to be handled in-memory, then you might as well choose `DataTable` - it will save you a lot of bug-hunting.

If the data doesn't need to be buffered in memory, I'd use `IDataReader` and let the consumer pull the data down themselves.

I should stress that `DataTable` is never my first choice of API, but it may be pragmatic here.

One other option is a generic method `ExecuteQuery<T>(..)` that fills the data into `T` instances, perhaps usig something like dapper-dot-net.